# Pinterest, Pin CSS Style

Tags: css, sass, less, pinterest

I'm trying to get the CSS for a Pin Style right. I'm trying to get the exact Pinterest Pin Style, that means that the image is **filling** the container/box and below there are the stats...

The Image below shows a Pinterest Pin that i'm trying to make. Does anyone know the Css that is required for the image to Fill the container/box ?

Thank you

[image: Pinterest Pin Style]

Comment: Im here now -> http://i.imgur.com/lEeneC8.png , but can't get the image to fill in.

Comment: Not sure if this will help but I did some digging before on Pinterest's pins in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080593/mouseover-image-effect/14080794#14080794

Comment: Thanks Aug, its not about the problem i have right now. But it helped me with my mouseover :)

Comment: I don't understand what's the difference with default pin styles.

Comment: Hey Andrey, im here right now -> i.imgur.com/lEeneC8.png . As you see the Image does not fill the Box (zoom in for better view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make sure your image is the same width as its container element. Set the width on your container to the same width as your image and make sure there is no padding in your container or margins on the top or sides of your image.

```
<div class="container">
  <img width="200">
  <div class="meta">
    text
  </div>
</div>

.container { width: 200px; padding: 0; }
.container img { margin: 0; }
```

Pinterest's code gets a bit more complex but you can always use an inspector to see what they're doing specifically.

Comment: Oh god.. So many Hours and i didn't think about this ... Thank you Sir :)